# Compiling Objective-c programs on Ubuntu and a good IDE for the same?

Tags: ide, compiler, objective-c

I am trying my hands on Objective-C and I want to know how can I compile the programs in Ubuntu. Can I do it with GCC or is something else required?
Also, please recommend a good IDE/Editor for Objective-C. I am a fan of Geany but it does not support Objective-C. I don't want to use VIM or Emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu includes GCC's Objective C compiler in the `gobjc` package.  I don't have a good suggestion for an IDE though.  There are multiple text editors with support for Objective C syntax highlighting.

While you've ruled out Emacs and VIM, `gedit` might cover your needs.  It has syntax highlighting and provides some IDE-style features with the `gedit-developer-plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Project Center](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/ProjectCenter.html) IDE from GNUstep is [available in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/projectcenter.app): `apt-get install projectcenter.app`